# for loop with a single semicolon throws the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')"

Tags: javascript, for-loop, iterator, console, break

The following for loop works fine

```js
for (let count = 0;; count++) {
  console.log(count);
  if (count >= 3)
    break
}
```

It throws an error when there's only one semicolon `;` instead of two

```js
for (let count = 0; count++) {
  console.log(count)
  if (count >= 3)
    break
}
```

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')

Comment: Its compilation issue, to deep dive into this may be go through https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Missing_semicolon_before_statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just how the for loops syntax works. The semicolons in the for loop separate three different expressions from each other - the "variable initializing" statement, the "stop condition" expression, and the "post-iteration" expression (I'm just making up names here, but they fit their purpose).

So, in this line of code:

```
for (let count = 0;; count++)
```

By putting two semicolons there, you're basically saying that there is no middle expression, i.e. there is no stop condition for this for-loop. You can omit any section you like. `for (;;)` is a valid loop too, and does the exact same thing as `while (true)`. The important thing is, those two semicolons are *always* required in the loop.

If, for example, you wrote this line of code:

```js
for (let count = 0; count++)
```

You're only supplying two of the three required expressions. Which two are you supplying? Is count++ the stop condition? Or is it the after-each-iteration action? Instead of the compiler guessing at your intentions, it just throws a syntax error and requires you to use two semicolons to make it clear that your intentions were for it to be interpreted as `for (let count = 0;; count++)`, not `for (let count = 0; count++;)`.

Learn more about this c-style for loop on MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).